# pimcore: MySQLi Support not Working as Expected

Tags: php, pimcore

I'm new to pimcore. On installation, I set the database format to `mysqli`,
and I want to access a different database schema on the same server through `mysqli`.

Here's my code:

```
    $db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "db2");
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting this error:

> Warning:  include_once(Website\Magento\mysqli.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
>        in C:\dev\htdocs\pimcore\vendor\zendframework\zendframework1\library\Zend\Loader.php on line 134

How can I enable the `mysqli` support in pimcore again?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that you have the mysqli extension installed? Maybe Pimcore is automatically using PDO as a fallback. Does the mysqli work if you use it outside Pimcore project?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
$db = new \mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "db2");
```

I guess your code is in a class which uses the namespace `Website\Magento` so you have to tell PHP that you want to use the class  `mysqli` from the root-namespace.

But this is just plain PHP and has nothing to do with pimcore ;-) 
Please have a look at the following link, it describes in detail how to work with namespaces in PHP: http://php.net/namespaces